# How to import Wikivoyage tourism information to OsmAnd

Tags: offline, maps, navigation, offline-map, osmand

[Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org) is a collaborative travel guide covering 25,000 destinations.
It details hotels/restaurants/bars/attractions with opening hours etc.

[OsmAnd](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=osmand&fdid=net.osmand.plus) is an open source navigation Android app.

How to make OsmAnd display all of the data from Wikivoyage?
So that when scrolling the map, one can see the hotels/etc with their details, even when offline.

Answer (score 1):

**(Update: The data is now available as `.gpx` at https://github.com/baturin/wikivoyage-listings)**

1) Download the latest `.obf` file at https://sourceforge.net/projects/wikivoyage/files/Listings-as-OBF/

2) Using any [file management app](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=manager&fdid=com.cyanogenmod.filemanager.ics), move the `.obf` file to the root of your OsmAnd folder, probably `/sdcard/osmand/`.

3) Start OsmAnd, and enable the "POI > Any" layer (accessible in MENU > Layers).

4) Hotels/etc should appear, visible in orange circle. Sometimes it does not work immediately, in such cases just restart your phone.

Answer (score 1):

In OsmAnd 3.0 the wikivoyage database is accessible for downloads same as wikipedia. Each article consists of 2 parts: html article itself and GPX information to be displayed on the map

Comment: Wonderful! By default it does seem to only include articles, though, rather than every museum/restaurant/etc? So for instance when you go to the city of Brighton you will see only one point for the whole city, rather than one point per attraction like in my answer.

Comment: Wikivoyage is city/trip based wikipedia, most of the objects are links to the Wikipedia which was already supported. For that purpose we support Points section which is Listings from the article where you could see points on the map.

Comment: If I understand correctly, when I enable `Configure map > POI Overlay > Tourism` the Wikipedia listings that are linked to Wikidata appear as orange pins on the map? It is wonderful, but most listings are unfortunately not linked to Wikidata because they are not notable enough or have zero reference in the printed world (ex: food shack in savanna area). Would it be possible for you to reuse data from the much more complete https://github.com/baturin/wikivoyage-listings (available as CSV/SQL/GPX, updated every two weeks)? Thanks a lot for integrating Wikivoyage, that's super useful! :-)

Comment: Nope, each Article has a link to Points which represents GPX and it is a complete list from Wikivoyage  (from each point there is a redirection to Wikipedia if exists). GPX file could be configured to be displayed on the map.